# Set maximum upload for images with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, image-uploading

I´d like to prevent a user to upload images bigger than a determinated size (i.e. 1 MB) using if possible htaccess.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You might use the [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive. Note how it governs the size of the *entire* request, so the actual size of the largest allowed file will be smaller. You can combine it with an [`ErrorDocument 413`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) to make the error message more user-friendly.

Also, if you're on a shared host, there's a chance the system administrator doesn't [allow overriding](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) the value in a htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of "php_value upload_max_filesize" in htaccess file.
Please refer the link below. Though, the example on link given below is for increasing the filesize, you can use the same for limiting the filesize.
http://www.maheshchari.com/increase-php-file-upload-limit/

The link below can also help you. Checkout the section entitled "Modifying the .htaccess file". Though, the example is for moodle, it can give you basic idea to sort-out the problem.
http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/File_upload_size

With all due respect, i would like to add that "php_value upload_max_filesize" is used to limit the filesize. Whereas "LimitRequestBody" directive is used to limit entire body size.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html (Checkout the section entitled with "LimitRequestBody Directive")

Comment: I think I dont explain myself. I dont want a webmaster user to upload images bigger than 1MB. As he does not know the htaccess file exists, Ia want to take that advantage. Its a web hosted on my server and despite I have trained him to not to do it, he keeps on uploading huge images that load the server and makes user experience sloooooww downloads. I have tried adding **php_value upload_max_filesize 1M** to htaccess but if I upload a jpg file bigger than 1MB I still can so....Thank you